# Expression resolves to an unused function when trying to call removeFirst()

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanted to try to build an own OperationQueue. 
I hoped to build an array of functions with completionHandler (operations).
In my executeNext function i tried to delete the first operation from my array of functions.

Unfortunately i got the error (see title). I am not sure why?

```
   class MainOperationQueue {

    private var operations : [(_ completion:()->()) -> ()] = []

    func addOperation(_ op: @escaping (_ completion:()->())->()) {
        operations.append(op)
    }

    func executeNext() {
        if operations.count > 0 {
            let op = operations.first
            op!() {

            }
            operations.remove(at: 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code does not call `removeFirst()`. Is this the real code? And the operation type is really `(() -> Void) -> Void)`, a closure which passes a closure and has no return type?

Comment: yeah, you are right, i tried different thing when writing the post, but it call remove(at:0) which is pretty much the same... ;)

Comment: `remove(at` usually does not display the `unused` warning.

Comment: try it. it does. and it is NOT a warning - it is an error. Because of a warning i would'nt have asked... :D

Comment: I tried it. It does not. Are you using `SwiftLint` or another *nitpicker*?

Comment: @vadian: see my "temporary" answer -> i will delete it, but here i cannot show images in the comment

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are talking about SwiftUI which follows other rules.

Comment: ah ok....I thought, class definitions would behave the same as in Swift...so i learned again something ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *Removing Elements* in [Array - Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array)

```
func remove(at: Int) -> Element
```

Removes and returns the element at the specified position. 
Thus

```
operations.remove(at: 0)
```

is returning a function from operations which is then not used. To solve just ignore the result:-

```
_ = operations.remove(at: 0)
```